# Collapse Table when nothing is generated

Tags: php, jquery, css, html-table

With this PHP code I generate a table. with content from the database. Now I want to collapse it if it didn't generate any content.

It's only a part of the table otherwise there would be to much code. The rest of the table is the same.

```
  <table class="table">
      <tr class="day">
        <th>
        <?php
          $j = 0;
          thisDayIs($weekDays[$j]);
          echo "<br>";
          echo $weekDays[$j];
          $j++;
         ?>
        </th>
        <?php
          $datum = $weekDays[$j];

          $parameters = array(':date'=>$datum,
                              ':aid'=>$id);
          $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT opdrachten.KRITISCHE_DATUM, opdrachten.PLANNINGS_DATUM, opdrachten.OPDRACHTID, onderzoekactiviteiten.A_UITVOERDER
                                FROM opdrachten
                                INNER JOIN onderzoekactiviteiten
                                ON opdrachten.OPDRACHTID=onderzoekactiviteiten.OPDRACHTID
                                WHERE PLANNINGS_DATUM = :date
                                AND A_UITVOERDER = :aid");
          $sth->execute($parameters);
          while ($row = $sth->fetch())
          {
            $cutKritDate = substr($row['KRITISCHE_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            $cutPlanDate = substr($row['PLANNINGS_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            echo "<td>Krit= " . $cutKritDate . "<br>";
            echo "Plan= " . $cutPlanDate . "<br>";
            echo "Opdracht= " . $row['OPDRACHTID'] . "</td>";
          }

        ?>
      </tr>


      <tr class="day">
        <th>
        <?php
          thisDayIs($weekDays[$j]);
          echo "<br>";
          echo $weekDays[$j];
          $j++;
        ?>
        </th>
        <?php
          $datum = $weekDays[$j];

          $parameters = array(':date'=>$datum,
                              ':aid'=>$id);
          $sth = $pdo->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT opdrachten.KRITISCHE_DATUM, opdrachten.PLANNINGS_DATUM, opdrachten.OPDRACHTID, onderzoekactiviteiten.A_UITVOERDER
                                FROM opdrachten
                                INNER JOIN onderzoekactiviteiten
                                ON opdrachten.OPDRACHTID=onderzoekactiviteiten.OPDRACHTID
                                WHERE PLANNINGS_DATUM = :date
                                AND A_UITVOERDER = :aid");
          $sth->execute($parameters);
          while ($row = $sth->fetch())
          {
            $cutKritDate = substr($row['KRITISCHE_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            $cutPlanDate = substr($row['PLANNINGS_DATUM'], 0, 10);
            echo "<td>Krit= " . $cutKritDate . "<br>";
            echo "Plan= " . $cutPlanDate . "<br>";
            echo "Opdracht= " . $row['OPDRACHTID'] . "</td>";
          }

        ?>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

I've tried something with jquery but it didn't work at all.

jquery:

```
$('.day').click(function()
{
    $(this).nextUntil('tr.day').slideToggle(1000);
});
```

I have 5 rows and no idea what to do i have been struggeling a lot with this and can't find a solution.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can check for rows. if it is 0, display some kind of message

Comment: Hi, your main problem right now is that you have your PHP processing between your layout. 1st step: try to divide it into processing part and layout part. How this is done is described here: https://gist.github.com/adrian-enspired/9ed2542a695e2ebe30aa - if you've done that, you can simply do something like `<table class="table <?php if($noEntries) { echo 'table-collapsed'; } ?>"`. Now you can easily style your table with the `.table-collapsed` selector.

Comment: @Xatenev You are right, but I have my code in a loop. So that makes organizing a lot harder. (that's atleast my experience)

Comment: It really isn't.

Comment: @Xatenev so any tips on the loops?

Comment: You can probably check for `td` in your JQuery code. Something like `$("tr.day td").length` if this is more than 0, means the data exists else collapse the table.

Comment: @MilanChheda That is a really bad solution. This should not be solved by javascript..

Comment: @ScorpionCode As I said above - move all your processing logic on top of your script. Prepare appropriate variables that you need later.

Comment: @Xatenev are you referring to the 'border-collapse' style property? Because what you said didn't work. And I wonder if there is any posibility to collapse a collum?